# Can old landlord withdraw money using ACH information without my consent

Tags: residential-lease, tenant, covid-19, breaking-the-lease

My landlord uses a web client called `securecafe` to automate rent payments. I enrolled to auto payment using ACH.

Due to covid-19 I had to terminate my lease early and leave my apartment. My landlord is asking for 4 months of rent for termination. I am not planning to pay this ~$11K and will fight it since my early termination is solely due to the pandemic.

My question is : My landlord has my routing and account numbers since I entered these in the auto payment system. After moving out I removed auto payment order and also removed my bank account information from the system. However it is *technically* possible my landlord to be keeping these numbers although the tenant automation system shows that there are no electronic checks nor auto payment orders when I log in to my account. Can my old landlord still withdraw money using my electronic check information without my consent?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the pandemic allowed you to terminate the lease without paying it out?

Comment: As far as I know, your bank will permit an ACH withdrawal by anyone who has your account and routing number.  They won't verify that you consented, though if you can show that the transaction was unauthorized, you should in principle be able to get the money refunded.  However, it may be simpler to close the account and prevent it from becoming an issue in the first place.